# Binary Search Ascending Order Array C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to search an array using a binary search algorithm when the array is in ascending order. I don't know why every single time I search for a value it says it isn't in the array... Here is my code.

```
int main()
{
    int found, value;
    int array[] = {0,2,2,3,5,9,11,12,12,12,13,17,18,19,19,34}; // array to be searched

    cout << "Enter an integer to search for:" << endl;
    cin >> value;

    found = binarySearch(array, SIZE, value); //function call to perform the binary search
                                              //on array looking for an occurrence of value
    if (found == -1)
        cout << "The value " << value << " is not in the list" << endl;
    else
    {
        cout << "The value " << value << " is in position number "
             << found + 1 << " of the list" << endl; 
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

//**********BINARY SEARCH**********
int binarySearch(int array[],int numElems,int value) //function heading
{
    int first = 0;                  // First element of list
    int last = numElems - 1;        // last element of the list
    int middle;                     // variable containing the current 
                                    // middle value of the list

    while (first <= last)
    {
        middle = first + (last - first) / 2; 

    if (array[middle] == value)
        return middle;             // if value is in the middle, we are done

    else if (array[middle] < value)
        last = middle - 1;         // toss out the second remaining half of
                                   // the array and search the first 
    else
        first = middle + 1;        // toss out the first remaining half of
                                   // the array and search the second
    }

    return -1;                     // indicates that value is not in the array
}
```

Comment: `std::lower_bound` may help.

Comment: As I pointed out on your other question, vandalism of questions, even your own, is not allowed on SO.  Subscriber content [is owned by SO after you post it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336993/op-accepts-answer-then-vandalizes-the-question/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your condition for binary search is inverted.

if `array[middle] < value` then you want to search for your element in upper half and not the lower half.

Answer (score 0):

Exchange `last = middle - 1` and `first = middle + 1`, and binary search would work fine.

Lets search for 7.

`2 3 5 6 [7] 8 8 9`

`0 1 2 3  4  5 6 7`

`^f`....`^m`............`^l`

`m = (7 + 0) / 2 = 3`

Element with index 3 is 6.
`6 < 7`. Then we should change `first` to `mid + 1`.

If mid value is less than value for search, then we should change `first`, so that value for search is still in interval `[first; last]`